# Is there a way to convert 1K to 1000 and 1M to 1,000,000 In LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I need to sum a large data set, but the values are entered as K or M. Is there a way to change these convert these to numerical values? I was thinking of using find and replace to change M to 000000, but that won't work for values such as 1.25M. Is there an easy solution to this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the values are in a column (column A in this example), add a second column with this formula and fill down to match the values you need to convert:

```
=IFNA(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*CHOOSE(MATCH(RIGHT(A1,1),{"K","M"},0),1000,1000000),A1)
```

The formula looks for "K" or "M" with `MATCH(RIGHT(A1,1),{"K","M"},0)`, which returns 1 for "K" or 2 for "M". The `CHOOSE` function returns 1,000 or 1,000,000, which is multiplied by `LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)`. The `LEFT` function removes the "K" or "M".

What happens if the value does not end with "K" or "M"? In these cases, `MATCH` returns #NA, and `IFNA` returns the value unchanged. The formula converts positive and negative values, as well a values with decimal places (for example, 1.25M converts to 1,250,000).

The same method is easily extended to convert billions (1,000,000,000):

```
=IFNA(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*CHOOSE(MATCH(RIGHT(A1,1),{"K","M","B"},0),1000,1000000,1000000000),A1)
```

Answer (score -1):

public class samplecode {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "257K";
    try {
        Integer num = Integer.parseInt(str);
        System.out.println(str);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        char type = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
        Integer num = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
        switch (type) {
        case 'K':
            System.out.println(num * 1000);
            break;
        case 'M':
            System.out.println(num * 1000000);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  The best answers teach the reader so they understand how to solve similar problems the next time.  Could you expand the answer to explain how the code works and what the reader needs to do with it to use it?  Thanks.

Comment: Also, note that the question mentions the possibility of string values like “1.25M”.